# Configure context-root with multiple applications

Tags: java, glassfish-4

I need to configure a glassfish server to deploy multiple applications under the same root

For example
127.0.0.1/myroot/app1
127.0.0.1/myroot/app2

I can achieve this by setting the context-root node of each application I want to deploy....

```
<application version="7" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd">
  <display-name>app1</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>app1-war.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>myroot/app1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

The problem is that this type of declaration is static and is linked to the source code. I would like the configuration to be dependent on the server where the applications are installed or alternatively define a path depending on a variable:

```
<context-toot>{myvar}/app1</context-root>
```

Thanks for any help